# Async/Await exception handling

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

My question is based on article [*Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

So i have this code

```
    async static void AsyncVersion()
    {
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        string url1 = "http://rsdn.ru";
        string url2 = "http://gotdotnet.ru";
        string url3 = "http://blogs.msdn.com";

        var webRequest1 = WebRequest.Create(url1);
        Console.WriteLine("Before webRequest1.GetResponseAsync(). Thread Id: {0}",
            Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        ...
```

so this code throws exception, for example when i haven't inet connection. So when i'm following msdn's guidances and change signature of method to Task (instead of void), but after this it devour all exceptions, but hey aren't handle by external `catch` block.

Entire code is below

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    class Program
    {
        async static Task AsyncVersion()
        {
            Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            string url1 = "http://rsdn.ru";
            string url2 = "http://gotdotnet.ru";
            string url3 = "http://blogs.msdn.com";

            var webRequest1 = WebRequest.Create(url1);
            Console.WriteLine("Before webRequest1.GetResponseAsync(). Thread Id: {0}",
                Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

            var webResponse1 = await webRequest1.GetResponseAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}, elapsed {2}ms. Thread Id: {3}", url1,
                webResponse1.ContentLength, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds,
                Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

            var webRequest2 = WebRequest.Create(url2);
            Console.WriteLine("Before webRequest2.GetResponseAsync(). Thread Id: {0}",
                Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

            var webResponse2 = await webRequest2.GetResponseAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}, elapsed {2}ms. Thread Id: {3}", url2,
                webResponse2.ContentLength, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds,
                Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

            var webRequest3 = WebRequest.Create(url3);
            Console.WriteLine("Before webRequest3.GetResponseAsync(). Thread Id: {0}",
                Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            var webResponse3 = await webRequest3.GetResponseAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}, elapsed {2}ms. Thread Id: {3}", url3,
                webResponse3.ContentLength, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds,
                Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Main thread id: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                Task task = new Task(() => AsyncVersion());
                task.Start();
                Console.WriteLine("Right after AsyncVersion() method call");
                //Ожидаем завершения асинхронной операции
                task.Wait();
                Console.WriteLine("Asyncronous task finished!");

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //Все исключения в TPL пробрасываются обернутые в AggregateException
                Console.WriteLine("Exceptopn: {0}", e.Message);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

old version:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    class Program
    {
        async static void AsyncVersion()
        {
            Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            string url1 = "http://rsdn.ru";
            string url2 = "http://gotdotnet.ru";
            string url3 = "http://blogs.msdn.com";

            var webRequest1 = WebRequest.Create(url1);
            Console.WriteLine("Before webRequest1.GetResponseAsync(). Thread Id: {0}",
                Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

            var webResponse1 = await webRequest1.GetResponseAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}, elapsed {2}ms. Thread Id: {3}", url1,
                webResponse1.ContentLength, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds,
                Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

            var webRequest2 = WebRequest.Create(url2);
            Console.WriteLine("Before webRequest2.GetResponseAsync(). Thread Id: {0}",
                Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

            var webResponse2 = await webRequest2.GetResponseAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}, elapsed {2}ms. Thread Id: {3}", url2,
                webResponse2.ContentLength, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds,
                Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

            var webRequest3 = WebRequest.Create(url3);
            Console.WriteLine("Before webRequest3.GetResponseAsync(). Thread Id: {0}",
                Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            var webResponse3 = await webRequest3.GetResponseAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}, elapsed {2}ms. Thread Id: {3}", url3,
                webResponse3.ContentLength, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds,
                Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Main thread id: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                Task task = new Task(AsyncVersion);
                task.Start();
                Console.WriteLine("Right after AsyncVersion() method call");
                //Ожидаем завершения асинхронной операции
                task.Wait();
                Console.WriteLine("Asyncronous task finished!");

            }
            catch (System.AggregateException e)
            {
                //Все исключения в TPL пробрасываются обернутые в AggregateException
                Console.WriteLine("AggregateException: {0}", e.InnerException.Message);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to reorder some of your awaits, right now you still do each request one at a time, if you kept the `Task` from each `GetResponseAsync()` instead of awaiting right away you could let all 3 run at once and then at the end do your awaiting. So for your responses change your code to `var webResponse1Task = webRequest1.GetResponseAsync();` then at the bottom of your function do `var webResponse1 = await webResponse1Task; var webResponse2 = await webResponse2Task; var webResponse3 = await webResponse3Task;`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
new Task(() => AsyncVersion())
```

This is the problematic part. The `Task` constructor doesn't understand `async`, so it ignores the `Task` returned from `AsyncVersion`. (The fact that you had to use lambda instead of writing `AsyncVersion` directly should have alerted you that something weird is happening.)

You have several options how to fix this (best options last):

1. Use `Task<Task>` and `Wait()` for the inner `Task` too:

   ```
   Task<Task> task = new Task<Task>(AsyncVersion);
   task.Start();
   task.Result.Wait();
   ```
2. Use `Unwrap()` to change the `Task<Task>` to `Task` that represents both `Task`s:

   ```
   Task<Task> task = new Task<Task>(AsyncVersion);
   task.Start();
   task.Unwrap().Wait();
   ```
3. Use `Task.Run()`, which does understand `async`:

   ```
   Task task = Task.Run(() => AsyncVersion());
   task.Wait();
   ```
4. Don't start a `Task` at all, just call the `async` method:

   ```
   Task task = AsyncVersion();
   task.Wait();
   ```

Comment: +1. IMO the best option is (4) - just call the `async` method and `Wait` on the returned task. Note to Alex: Normally you do *not* want to call `Wait` or `Result` on asynchronous tasks, but you have to in this case because it's a Console application. If you were doing this in a WinForms/WPF/ASP.NET app, you should use `await` instead of `Wait`.